# Update Table using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

Can someone tell me why the following code is not updating StudentIDs in LINQPad?

```
var studentsList = Students.Select(t => t);

int newStudentID = 10001;
foreach(Student s in studentsList)
{      
   s.StudentID = newStudentID;            
   newStudentID = newStudentID + 1;   
}

SubmitChanges();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is the `StudentID` a primary key in the table?

Comment: I wanted to make StudentID as the primary key after loading the sequential numbers. To answer your question, no, it was not a primary key when I ran this query.

Answer (score 0):

not sure; i tried to write code to test this using the snippet you gave but that would compile under LinqPad; here's what i used:

```
public class Student
{
    public string name; 
    public int StudentId; 
}

void Main()
{
    Student[] Students = 
    new Student[] 
        { 
            new Student { name="a", StudentId = 0}, 
            new Student { name="b", StudentId = 0}, 
            new Student { name="c", StudentId = 0}, 
            new Student { name="d", StudentId = 0}
        };

    var studentsList = Students.Select(t => t);

    int newStudentID = 10001;
    foreach(var s in studentsList)
    {      
       s.StudentId = newStudentID;            
       newStudentID = newStudentID + 1;   
    }

    foreach(var s in studentsList)
    {      
       System.Console.WriteLine(s.name + ": " + s.StudentId.ToString());
    }
}
```

and here was the output:

```
a: 10001
b: 10002
c: 10003
d: 10004
```

so it looks like that much worked ok.  if you can give enough context to have a running example of your code i'd be happy to check it out further.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. If I dump the studentsList before calling the "SubmitChanges", it is showing the correct updated values. While researching this issue, I found an article on how it can be done easily. I will post my findings. Thanks again!

Comment: Eventhough I don't know why it is not working in LinqPad, this article helped me to update the table with a sinle Update statement: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/creating-a-sequential-record-number-field. The following query updated all rows correctly: declare @intCounter int set @intCounter = 10000 update Student SET @intCounter = StudentID = @intCounter + 1